Experiments with Tesla coil
What happens if you replace the secondary Tesla coil with a different conductor?
Everyone knows that the operation of the coil is a resonant structure. My question is, how the Tesla coil will behave if I replace the secondary coil with a flask of water, choosing the volume and shape of the water so that it resonates with the transformer coil?

Water will not resonate at those frequencies.  If you increase the frequency until it does, you have created a microwave.

I'm curious what theoretical considerations would you use and how would you prioritize them in order to design a system using water for your stated goals. Let's start there. Maybe then an answer might be possible to consider.

Epsilon relative (81) to water would change the value of the "capacitor" ...


what happens if you replace the secondary tesla coil with a different conductor? everyone knows that the operation of the coil is a resonant structure,

A Tesla coil is doubly resonant. Both the primary and the secondary are resonant, and they are tuned to the same frequency.

my question is how the tesla coil will behave if I replace the secondary coil with a flask of water, choosing the volume and shape of the water so that it resonates with the transformer coil

Water doesn't resonate, at least not at the frequencies available to a TC primary type structure. The result would be little difference from operating with a primary alone.
People have used a simple primary from a TC for induction heating. Place a suitably lossy conductor in the centre of the primary, a large steel bolt makes for a good demonstration, and watch it get hot from eddy heating. This demonstration assumes a sufficiently powerful TC. You may need to use a physically smaller diameter primary to couple to a bolt well enough to heat it significantly.
Plain water would likely be too resistive to have any significant dissipation in it, and too high a thermal capacity to show any resulting temperature rise in a reasonable time. Increase the conductivity by dissolving some salt or other in it to try to mitigate the first issue.
